# No done handler with removePendingNotificationRequests?

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter

There is no done handler in `removePendingNotificationRequests` huh? How are you supposed to know *when* a request has been removed?

Suppose you have a table view or something showing these requests. And you remove one - you need to remove that cell row to reflect that. But as removePendingNotificationRequests is async, according to the docs, it sounds like it would be incorrect to assume that requests would always be removed instantly.